# Proportionately distribute value among a set of values integer only

Tags: java, algorithm, math, calculation

I'm in this weird situation where in I get all the test cases passed except for this one (same 3 numbers).
I want to proportionately distribute certail cash among the values in the array declared.
I want the proportion to be in Int or without decimals.
Please help me with this test case :(

```
 public class DistProp{
    public static void main(String[] args){
    double[] a={300,300,300};
    double newA[]= new double[a.length];
    double aTotal=0;
    for(int i=0;i<a.length;i++){
      aTotal+=a[i];
    }
    double cash=100;
    System.out.println("cash:"+cash);
// this is just to show diff between running total and normal proporational distribution.
    System.out.println("before");
    double beforeTotal=0,afterTotal=0;
    for(int i=0;i<a.length;i++){
      double tmp =(a[i]/aTotal)*cash;
      System.out.println("a["+a[i]+"]="+tmp);
      beforeTotal+=tmp;
    }
    System.out.println("before Total:"+beforeTotal);
    System.out.println("after");
    double runningTotal = 0.0,oldRunningTotal=0.0;
    for(int i=0;i<a.length;i++){
      oldRunningTotal=runningTotal;
      runningTotal+=(a[i]/aTotal)*cash;
      newA[i]= (int)runningTotal - (int)oldRunningTotal;
    }
    for(int i=0;i<newA.length;i++){
      double tmp =newA[i];
      System.out.println("a["+a[i]+"]="+tmp);
      afterTotal+=tmp;
    }
    System.out.println("after Total:"+afterTotal);
  }
}
```

The Output That i get is :

```
cash:100.0
before
a[300.0]=33.33333333333333
a[300.0]=33.33333333333333
a[300.0]=33.33333333333333
before Total:99.99999999999999
after
a[300.0]=33.0
a[300.0]=33.0
a[300.0]=33.0
after Total:99.0
```

and not a total of 100.

Comment: Can you assign a(2)=100-a(1)-a(0)? in this way, the total will be right.

Comment: I can use this, is there any other better way?

Comment: If you ask for a "better way", you should specify some metric according to which you want it to be better. Depending on that there might or might not be a "better way".